# IIS6 + HttpModule: This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode

Tags: iis-6, httpmodule

I am using IIS6, I've written an HttpModule, and I get this error?  After googling the web I find that this problem is caused by the .NET framework 3.5, so I put this on a machine where I didn't install .NET 3.5, but the problem is still there!

Comment: Could you elaborate on what your module is doing?

Comment: check the if the user's password is exprided then force he to change it.

Comment: You need to provide code showing where the error occurs.

Answer (score 39):

My attempt at psychic debugging: you're using a statement like:

```
Response.Headers("X-Foo") = "bar"
```

If this is indeed the case, changing this as shown below will work around the problem:

```
Response.AddHeader("X-Foo", "bar")
```

Comment: Will `response.Headers.Location = new Uri(...);` break IIS6 and give a 500 `Internal Server Error`?

Answer (score 7):

Only IIS7 supports the integrated pipeline.  On IIS7 a HttpModule can participate in all requests coming to the web server not just those targeting specific file extensions.

II6 uses what IIS7 calls the classic pipeline where a HttpModules can only get involved once the earlier ISAPI based pipeline determines that the script mapping requires the request to handed over to ASP.NET.

Answer (score 6):

Just came across this problem. Using IIS6 and .NET 3.5. Fix for me was to use `Response.AddHeader` instead of `Response.Headers.Add`. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by other answers, I've found that it's accessing the `Response.Headers` *object* that causes the "operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode" exception.

Avoid `.Headers` and call other (older?) helper functions like:

- `Response.AddHeader()`  and
- `Response.ClearHeaders()`  (in my case!)