# Can't download word document, throwing exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, download

I'm using response object to download word document which is stored in database as a content. It is throwing the following exception :

```
 SubStatusCode 'Response.SubStatusCode' threw an exception of type 'System.PlatformNotSupportedException'
 base {"This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode."} System.NotSupportedException  {System.PlatformNotSupportedException}
 Headers 'Response.Headers' threw an exception of type 'System.PlatformNotSupportedException'
```

I cannot able to view my file.. My code is as follows:

```
protected void btnResumedload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dtResumeInfo = new DataTable();

    dtResumeInfo = bc.ConvertByteToDataTable(objservice.getResumeInfo(int.Parse(Session["LoginId"].ToString())));
    if (dtResumeInfo.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        string doctype = dtResumeInfo.Rows[0]["ContentType"].ToString();
        string docname = dtResumeInfo.Rows[0]["FileName"].ToString();
        //
        try
        {
            Response.Buffer = false;
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.ContentType = doctype;
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
                     "attachment; filename=" + docname);
            //
            //Code for streaming the object while writing
            const int ChunkSize = 1024;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[ChunkSize];
            byte[] binary = (dtResumeInfo.Rows[0]["ContentData"]) as byte[];
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(binary);
            int SizeToWrite = ChunkSize;

            for (int i = 0; i < binary.GetUpperBound(0) - 1; i = i + ChunkSize)
            {
                if (!Response.IsClientConnected) return;
                if (i + ChunkSize >= binary.Length)
                    SizeToWrite = binary.Length - i;
                byte[] chunk = new byte[SizeToWrite];
                ms.Read(chunk, 0, SizeToWrite);
                Response.BinaryWrite(chunk);
                Response.Flush();
            }
            Response.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        lblmsg.Visible = true;
        lblmsg.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        lblmsg.Visible = true;
        lblmsg.Text = "No Resume Information Found.";
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like you're using the wrong platform for what you're trying to do.  What is the server running that you're downloading your data from?  IIS? version? etc...

Comment: Configuration: IIS Version 5.1,.NET Framework 3.5,xp

Comment: Is there any solution for this??? :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as though you are using the Response.Headers property which is only supported by the IIS 7.0 integrated pipeline mode.  See: [IIS6 + HttpModule: This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186548/iis6-httpmodule-this-operation-requires-iis-integrated-pipeline-mode)