# Error while downloading file using ASP.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, download

Below is code where AJAX send POST request

Basically I want to download a file from some location(full path) on page load

But when I this page is called no error is thrown page get call succesfully
Even I get file.Exist=true , Response is created but on browser nothing happens
I expecting file download dialog. on further debugging I found exception in Response object
**Headers = 'Response.Headers' threw an exception of type 'System.PlatformNotSupportedException'** 
**This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode**

I am running this web page in my localhost(visual studio development server). .net4 and VS2010

On Page Load Code:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        string path = Request.Form["path"];

       // string reportName=path.Substring( path.LastIndexOf("\\") ,path.Length);
        DAL.IO_helper i = new DAL.IO_helper();
        string fullpath = i.GetReportsPath() + path;

        FileInfo report = new FileInfo(fullpath);

        if (report.Exists)
        {


            Response.ClearContent();

            Response.ClearHeaders();
            // Add the file name and attachment, which will force the open/cancel/save dialog box to show, to the header
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + report.Name);

            // Add the file size into the response header
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", report.Length.ToString());

            // Set the ContentType
            Response.ContentType = ReturnExtension(report.Extension.ToLower());

            // Write the file into the response (TransmitFile is for ASP.NET 2.0. In ASP.NET 1.1 you have to use WriteFile instead)
            Response.TransmitFile(report.FullName);

            //Transmit file

            Response.Flush();

            // End the response
            Response.End();

        }
        else
        {
            Response.ClearContent();
            // End the response
            Response.End();
        }


    }
```

function

```
 private string ReturnExtension(string fileExtension)
        {
            switch (fileExtension)
            {

                case ".txt":
                    return "text/plain";
                case ".dat":
                    return "text/plain";
                case ".doc":
                    return "application/ms-word";
                case ".docx":
                    return "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
                case ".zip":
                    return "application/zip";
                case ".xls":
                    return "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                case ".xlsx":
                    return "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                case ".csv":
                    return "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                case ".pdf":
                    return "application/pdf";
                case ".xml":
                    return "application/xml";
                case ".sdxl":
                    return "application/xml";
                default:
                    return "application/octet-stream";
            }
        }
```

Comment: take a look at the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940100/cant-download-word-document-throwing-exception

Comment: @user1666620 I am using visual studio envelopment server

Comment: and that uses iis express to run the site when you launch it from VS.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, you can't do this with the WebDev development web server since it doesn't support the integrated pipeline mode.  The solution is to use IIS Express to host the page.  You still get full debugging integration and so on.

Handy links:

- [Enabling IIS Express support in VS2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2011/03/14/enabling-iis-express-support-in-vs-2010-sp1.aspx)
- [Visual Studio 2010 SP1 for Web Developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288080.aspx) (specifically the `IIS Express 7.5 Support` section)
- [Setting up Visual Studio 2010 and IIS Express](http://joel.net/setting-up-visual-studio-2010-and-iis-express)

Or just google `VS2010 IIS Express` for any number of other helpful hints.